# Split javascript file into several files

Tags: javascript, import, sass, export

I am using JS to implement various functionalities in my web application. 
So far I used one file (`main.js`), which is getting pretty big and messy. I would like to "split" this file into several files (e.g. `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js`) and later import them into `main.js`. This way my development would be tidy and clean and on the html side, I would only have to reference one js file.

Is there a better way to do this, than using [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and export statements?

Is there some sort of "preprocessor" like in SASS, which would combine _partialA.scss, _partialB.scss, _partialC.scss into main.scss?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not completely satisfied with webpack, so I wrote my own little script. Feel free to use it.

It will do the following:

- watch the folder defined in the source path.
- if it detects a change in any of the files in the source folder it will read all files in the source folder
  and write them into the destination.js file

To execute, just run node scriptname.js

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
'use strict';

const watch = require('node-watch');
let allFilesPath = [];
const pathDestination = './path/to/destination.js';
const source = 'source/folder/';

const fs = require('fs');
init();

function init() {
    fs.truncate(pathDestination, 0, function() {
        console.log('delete everything in', pathDestination);
    });

    const allFiles = fs.readdirSync(source);
    allFiles.forEach(function(element) {
        allFilesPath.push(source + element);
    });
    allFiles.forEach(function(element) {
        getFileContent(element);
    });
}

function getFileContent(file) {
    fs.readFile(source + file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(source + file + ' was added to ' + pathDestination);
            addToBundle(data);
        }
    });
}

function addToBundle(code) {
    fs.appendFile(pathDestination, code, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

watch(allFilesPath, function(evt, filename) {
    console.log(filename, 'changed');
    init();
    console.log();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 imports and bundle your code using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: this looks interesting. Let me dive into that